# Is high school GPA included in IPEDs NCES databases?

Tags: databases, csv

I’m currently developing a computer tool which will sort through the US college and university NCES data provided in the IPEDs website to match users with potential universities. NCES shows university data on admission test scores, but I’m hoping to use the user’s high school GPA. I can’t find anything on accepted GPA scores in the NCES database contains data. It doesn’t seem to be an uncommon trait to search universities by, and would be quite useful to use when collecting/analyzing data. Is there any high school GPA info in NCES? if not, is there a similar database i can use to get GPAs without risk of copyright infringement?